# How to put variable in JSONB using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am doing an example of indexing with JSONB in PostgreSQL and want add random uuid to a piece of JSON like below. However I can't get the syntax just right the closest I have got is `"{"lookup_id": " || uuid || "}"`.

```
But I require
{"lookup_id": "92b3b21a-a87c-1798-5d91-3dbf3043c209"}
```

My code is:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, json)
SELECT x.id, '{
    "lookup_id": " || uuid || "
   }'::jsonb 
FROM generate_series(1,100) AS x(id),
     uuid_in(md5(now()::text)::cstring) AS uuid;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`row_to_json`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) function:

```
select x.id, row_to_json(r.*)::jsonb
from generate_series(1,100) AS x(id)
    cross join (select uuid_in(md5(now()::text)::cstring) as lookup_id) as r;
```

**update**

first, you can use `uuid` so you can create unique uids:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";

with cte as (
    select
        *, uuid_generate_v4() as uuid
    from generate_series(1,5) AS x(id)
)
select distinct uuid from cte

------------------------------------------------
"e980c784-8aae-493f-90fb-1091280fe4f7"
"45a80660-3be8-4538-a039-13d97d6306af"
"5380f285-5d6b-467a-a83a-7fdc5c0ebc4c"
"7a435b36-95d3-49fc-808f-359838a866ed"
"3164a544-a2c9-4cd0-b0c4-199a99986cea"
```

next, merging this to your existing `json`. The stupid and easiest way for now could be something like this:

```
with cte as (
    select
        '{"a":1}'::json as j, uuid_generate_v4() as uuid
    from generate_series(1,5) AS x(id)
)
select 
    left(j::text, length(j::text) - 1) || ', "uuid":' || to_json(uuid) || '}'
from cte
```

But you can also write some function to merge jsons together, or you can use `hstore` extension to merge jsons together:

```
with cte as (
    select
        id, '{"a":1, "b":2}'::json as data, uuid_generate_v4() as uuid
    from generate_series(1,5) AS x(id)
), cte2 as (
    select 
        id,
        (
            select hstore(array_agg(r.key), array_agg(r.value))
            from (
                select *
                from json_each_text(c.data) as j
                union all
                select 'uuid', c.uuid::text
            ) as r
        ) as data
    from cte as c
)
select
    id, hstore_to_json(data)
from cte2
```

And I'm sure bigger experts on PostgreSQL could advice more elegant way to merge jsons together

Comment: Hey Roman, thanks for the reply but that gives me the same uuid 100 times. Also I need to add it like my example above as my jsonb is about 130 lines.